# Volley Android - Cannot resolve symbol 'ClientError'

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I'm trying to adapt this code https://github.com/smanikandan14/Volley-demo/blob/master/volleydemoapp/src/main/java/com/mani/volleydemo/JSONObjectRequestActvity.java into my own project.

When I try to make the JSONObjectResponse

```
jsonObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, builder.toString(), null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                parseFlickrImageResponse(response);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                showToast("JSON parse error");
            }
            stopProgress();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // Handle your error types accordingly.For Timeout & No connection error, you can show 'retry' button.
            // For AuthFailure, you can re login with user credentials.
            // For ClientError, 400 & 401, Errors happening on client side when sending api request.
            // In this case you can check how client is forming the api and debug accordingly.
            // For ServerError 5xx, you can do retry or handle accordingly.
            if( error instanceof NetworkError) {
            } else if( error instanceof ClientError) {
            } else if( error instanceof ServerError) {
            } else if( error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
            } else if( error instanceof ParseError) {
            } else if( error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
            } else if( error instanceof TimeoutError) {
            }

            stopProgress();
            showToast(error.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

But this error appears:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'ClientError'
```

I've tried to import volley in several ways, but none of them seems to work. (.jar, compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0', compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19', etc).

By the way, I'm using Android Studio.

EDIT:

My gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tigerspike.interview.oriolgarcia.tigerspickr"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: use only one of them. I'm using `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'`

Comment: Hi! Yes, I'm using just one of them. The list I wrote is the different options I've tried to use.

Comment: can you post your gradle file

Comment: Yes, I've edited my original question